# Sending data properly from React to Ruby on Rails API Endpoint

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, api

I'm working on posting data from a React Form to a Ruby on Rails API, about the React part, if just send the first item from an array using this code:

```
  const submitOrderHandler = async (userData) => {

    setIsSubmitting(true);
    await fetch("http://localhost:3000/ordertemps", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(cartCtx.items[0]),//please include user: userData
    });
    setIsSubmitting(false);
    setDidSubmit(true);
    cartCtx.clearCart();
  };
```

The Ruby on Rails API manage it and store it in the table, this is the output:

[image]

However, I need to store all the data selected by the user, so, to accomplish this task I updated my code like this:

```
  const submitOrderHandler = async (userData) => {
    const dataSelected = JSON.stringify(cartCtx.items);
    console.log(dataSelected);

    setIsSubmitting(true);
    await fetch("http://localhost:3000/ordertemps", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(cartCtx.items),//please include user: userData
    });
    setIsSubmitting(false);
    setDidSubmit(true);
    cartCtx.clearCart();
  };
```

The problem is I'm getting a 400 Status, so this is how the data looks from the FrontEnd:

[image]

This is the output from the Ruby on Rails Endpoint:

[image]

the source code of the Controller in charge to manage and store the data is this:

```
#POST /ordertemps
def create
    @ordertemp = Ordertemp.new(ordertemp_params)
    if @ordertemp.save
        render json: @ordertemp
    else
        render error: { error: 'Unable to create an order'}, status: 400
    end
end

private

def ordertemp_params
    #params.require(:ordertemp).permit( :clientName, :clientId, :amount, :mealid, :name, :price)
    params.require(:ordertemp).permit(:name, :amount, :price)
end
```

So, I'm assuming these facts:

1. the data is properly formatted from the FrontEnd.
2. For some reason my Ruby on Rails'Controller can't manage more than one element sent by the front end.

My question is: what am I missing in my controller to store all the data sent by the FrontEnd?

Thanks a lot for your comments

Comment: While sending multiple items from the front end, the parameters are in the form of array. Notice the `_json` parameter while sending multiple order items. 

If `params[:_json]` exist, now loop through the elements inside the `params[:_json]`. Each array element will have `name`, `amount`, `price` in it. Just access them and save it.

Answer (score 1):

Update your controller code as below:

```
#POST /ordertemps
def create
  begin
    params['_json'].each do |ordertemp_params|
      @ordertemp = Ordertemp.new(ordertemp_params)
      @ordertemp.save
    end
    head :no_content

  rescue => e
    render json: { error:  unable to create orders }, status: 400
  end
end
```

Hope this will help you.